# Why is the video output so slow (frame by frame) through OpenCV (Python)?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I'm building a neural network model and the detection.py file is really slow, regarding the speed of the output video (it is literally frame by frame).

I tried adjusting a few things, though still the same result - slow video. What can be the problem? Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import cv2
from utils import *
from model import *

seed = 11
rnd.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

videofile = "files/cardriving.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videofile)

model = make_model()
model.load_weights("weights/weights_best.h5")

lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([100, 100, 100])

stepSize=30

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Done")
        break

    #convert image to HSV from BGR
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #find the pixels that correspond to the road
    img_out = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)

    #clean from noisy pixels and keep the largest connected segment
    img_out = post_process(img_out)

    image_masked = frame.copy()

    #get masked image
    image_masked[img_out==0] = (0,0,0)
    s=0.25

    #resize images for computational efficiency
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=s, fy=s)
    image_masked = cv2.resize(image_masked, None, fx=s, fy=s)

    #run the sliding window detection process
    bbox_list, totalWindows, correct, score = detectionProcess(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), model, winH=50, winW=50, depth=3, nb_images=1, scale=1, stepSize=stepSize, thres_score=0.05)

    #draw the detections
    drawBoxes(frame, bbox_list)

    #draw detections and road masks
    cv2.imshow("video", sidebyside(frame, image_masked))
    k = cv2.waitKey(3)

    if(k & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        cv2.destroyWindow("video")
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

here is the utils.py file where I wrote the post_process and detectionProcess:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def scale_to_image(x, a=0, b=255):
    #min-max scaling for grayscale images
    ma=(np.max(x))
    if(ma==0):
        return x.astype(np.uint8)
    mi=(np.min(x))
    normalized_data = ((x.astype(np.float)-float(mi))/float(ma)) #normalize 0-1
    normalized_data = (normalized_data*b + a*(1-normalized_data)) #scale values
    return normalized_data.astype(np.uint8)

def nothing(x):
    pass

def channels3(x):
    #stack grayscale images together to increase the color channels to 3
    return np.dstack((x,x,x))

def sidebyside(x,y):
    #concatenate images side by side (horizontally)
    return np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)

def updown(x,y):
    #concatenate images up and down (vertically)
    return np.concatenate((x,y), axis=0)

def extractLargerSegment(maskROAD):

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(maskROAD.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, contours=None, hierarchy=None)

    maxA = 0
    maskTemp = np.zeros_like(maskROAD)

    if(len(contours) > 0):
        for h, cnt in enumerate(contours):
            if(cv2.contourArea(cnt) > maxA):
                cntMax = cnt
                maxA = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        mask = np.zeros(maskROAD.shape, np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(maskTemp, [cntMax], 0, 255, -1)
        maskROAD = cv2.bitwise_and(maskROAD, maskTemp)
    return maskROAD

def post_process(img):
    kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
    img_out = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=3)
    kernel = np.ones((20,20), np.uint8)
    img_out = cv2.dilate(img_out, kernel, iterations=5)

    img_out = extractLargerSegment(img_out)

    return img_out

def display(img_init, img_hsv, img_out2, img_out):
    mask = scale_to_image(np.dstack((img_out, np.zeros_like(img_out), np.zeros_like(img_out))))
    cv2.imshow("Output", updown(sidebyside(cv2.addWeighted(img_init, 1, mask, 0.3, 0), img_hsv), sidebyside(channels3(img_out), channels3(img_out2))))

def detectionProcess(frame, model, winH=32, winW=32, depth=1, nb_images=2, scale=1.2, stepSize=10, thres_score=0):
    index=0
    totalWindows=0
    correct=0

    bbox_list = []
    score = []

    for resized in pyramid(frame, scale=scale, minSize=(winH, winW), nb_images=nb_images):
        scale = frame.shape[0]/resized.shape[0]
        for (x,y,window) in sliding_window(resized, stepSize=stepSize, windowSize=(winH, winW)):
            if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] != winW:
                continue

            if(depth==1):
                window=cv2.cvtColor(window, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                window=np.expand_dims(window,3)
            
            window = window[None, :, :, :]

            totalWindows += 1

            class_out = model.predict((window.astype(np.float32))/255., batch_size=1)[0]

            if(class_out<thres_score):
                bbox_list.append(((int(x*scale)), int(y*scale), int((x+winW)*scale), int((y+winH)*scale)))
                score.append(class_out)
                correct+=1
        
        index+=1

    return bbox_list, totalWindows, correct, score

def sliding_window(image, stepSize, windowSize):
    #slide a window accross the image
    for y in range(0, image.shape[0], stepSize):
        for x in range(0, image.shape[1], stepSize):
            yield(x, y, image[y:y + windowSize[1], x:x + windowSize[0]])

def pyramid(image, scale=1.5, minSize=(30,30), nb_images=3):
    yield image
    count=0

    #keep looping over the pyramid
    while True:
        #compute new dimensions of an image and resize it
        w = int(image.shape[1]/scale)
        h = int(image.shape[0]/scale)

        image = cv2.resize(image, (w,h))
        count += 1
        scale = np.power((1/scale), count)

        if image.shape[0] < minSize[1] or image.shape[1] < minSize[0] or (count == nb_images):
            break

        yield image

def drawBoxes(frame, bbox_list):
    for i in range(len(bbox_list)):
        box = bbox_list[i]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (box[0], box[1]), (box[2], box[3]), (0, 255, 255), 2)
    
    return frame
```

Comment: use a profiler to figure out what's slow. My guess is your `detectionProcess` or possibly your `post_process` functions, but it's impossible to know from our side without more info. you could look into multiprocessing to allow processing on multiple frames at once if you need more speed. In one of my past posts, I wrote a demo of how to efficiently share video frames between processes with `multiprocessing.shared_memory`.

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong from first glance. I suspect that perhaps you could reduce some matrix operations. But first it is good to run profiler. E.g. this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/profiler.html

Comment: have you counted the number of `cvtColor` and `resize` calls you are making, not to mention the pyramid stuff, and you seem to want to apply a DNN (but haven't yet), which costs *a lot* more than any of those operations, usually.